# Content Top Drupal Theme

Tags: drupal, themes

I am looking for existing themes that has content top region so that I can put my menu there.

Any suggestion?

Comment: very close to not being a programming question!

Answer (score 2):

Zen theme for drupal has a ready to use 'content top' region - http://drupal.org/project/zen
This project is by far the best tool for creating custom drupal themes and also comes with a ready to use subtheme 'zen-classic' (it has a content-top region too)

If you are using D6 adding regions to your own theme is a no-brainer (http://drupal.org/theme-guide). Its not very difficult in D5 either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a base theme, consider this comparison:

http://www.chapterthree.com/blog/review-drupal-6-starter-themes

It's the best review I've seen of the base themes available for Drupal.